# Constructing a family of domains for application of method of continuity in optimal transportation

Tags: elliptic-pde, optimal-transportation

Anyway can help me about this paper?

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601086v4.pdf

I want to ask page 20, The author want to construct a family of subdomain for using method of continuity. But I can't understand what do he mean by the construction using (5.8) and the sentence follow by... How can he do the job?

pde optimal-transport

Comment: Please don't post on both MO and MSE at the same time. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719779/constructing-a-family-of-domains-for-application-of-method-of-continuity-in-opti